# Unknown Class: 'button' & invalid method decleration; return type required for findViewById

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-button

I am new to android, forgive my ignorance. I am attempting to add a button to my main activity, that when clicked will transition the app to a camera view.

#### main activity code:

```
package com.cerezaenterprises.swiftversionuno;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return true;
    }
    private Button button;
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)*****
    private void setupMessageButton() {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraView1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am having an issue where it is asterisked, stating
1st: (unknown class: 'button')
2nd: (Invalid method  declaration) for 'findViewById'
3rd: (Unknown class R.id.button)

#### activity_main.xml:

```xml
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id= "@+id/rootRL"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
    android:background = "@drawable/background">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Previous problem is solved, After solving my problem, updated code is.

```
package com.cerezaenterprises.swiftversionuno;


 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;



 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {
 private Button button;
     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraView1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
         });
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
         // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
         int id = item.getItemId();

         //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
         if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
             return true;
         }

         super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

         return true;
       }
 }
```

After fixing the first issue, and clicking on my camera button, my app crashes, and the log cat says "no zero argument constructor". Does anyone know how to resolve this ?? I am stuck. Here is my CameraView1 code:

```
package com.cerezaenterprises.swiftversionuno;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import static java.lang.System.loadLibrary;

/**
 * Extention of SurfaceView which starts a camera preview and decode video
 * content on the native side.
 */
public class CameraView1 extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        Camera.PreviewCallback {
    private static final String TAG = "LiveCamera";


    static {
        loadLibrary("LiveCamera");

    }

    public native void decode(Bitmap pTarget, byte[] pSource);

    private Camera mCamera;
    private byte[] mVideoSource;
    private Bitmap mBackBuffer;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public CameraView1(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Registers current class so that it listens to surface
        // event (creation, destruction and changes).
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        // Clears the flag keeping the surface from getting drawn.
        // Necessary when not drawing from a thread.
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // Acquires the default camera.
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            // Sets landscape mode to avoid complications related to
            // screen orientation handling.
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            // Registers callbacks. Automatic preview is deactivated
            // as we want to process data ourself (in a buffer).
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
        } catch (IOException eIOException) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder pHolder, int pFormat, int pWidth,
                               int pHeight) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();

        // Finds a suitable resolution.
        Size lSize = findBestResolution(pWidth, pHeight);

        // Prepares video source and back buffers.
        PixelFormat lPixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
        PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(mCamera.getParameters()
                .getPreviewFormat(), lPixelFormat);
        int lSourceSize = lSize.width * lSize.height
                * lPixelFormat.bitsPerPixel / 8;
        mVideoSource = new byte[lSourceSize];
        mBackBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(lSize.width, lSize.height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // Set-up camera size and video format. YCbCr_420_SP
        // should be the default on Android anyway.
        Camera.Parameters lParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        lParameters.setPreviewSize(lSize.width, lSize.height);
        lParameters.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
        mCamera.setParameters(lParameters);

        // Starts receiving pictures from the camera.
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    private Size findBestResolution(int pWidth, int pHeight) {
        List<Size> lSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        // Finds the biggest resolution which fits the screen.
        // Else, returns the first resolution found.
        Size lSelectedSize = mCamera.new Size(0, 0);
        for (Size lSize : lSizes) {
            if ((lSize.width <= pWidth) && (lSize.height <= pHeight)
                    && (lSize.width >= lSelectedSize.width)
                    && (lSize.height >= lSelectedSize.height)) {
                lSelectedSize = lSize;
            }
        }
        // Previous code assume that there is a preview size smaller
        // than screen size. If not, hopefully the Android API
        // guarantees that at least one preview size is available.
        if ((lSelectedSize.width == 0) || (lSelectedSize.height == 0)) {
            lSelectedSize = lSizes.get(0);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "findBestResolution: " + lSelectedSize.width + ","
                + lSelectedSize.height);
        return lSelectedSize;
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Releases camera which is a shared resource.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            // These variables can take a lot of memory. Gets rid of
            // them as fast as we can.
            mCamera = null;
            mVideoSource = null;
            mBackBuffer = null;
        }
    }

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] pData, Camera pCamera) {
        // New data has been received from camera. Processes it and
        // requests surface to be redrawn right after.
        decode(mBackBuffer, pData);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas pCanvas) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Draws resulting image at screen origin.
            pCanvas.drawBitmap(mBackBuffer, 0, 0, mPaint);
            // Enqueues buffer again to get next image.
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Log Cat beginning with crash:

```
 --------- beginning of crash
07-29 11:33:36.336    2074-2074/com.cerezaenterprises.swiftversionuno E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cerezaenterprises.swiftversionuno, PID: 2074
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.cerezaenterprises.swiftversionuno/com.cerezaenterprises.swiftversionuno.CameraView1}: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.cerezaenterprises.swiftversionuno.CameraView1 has no zero argument constructor
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.cerezaenterprises.swiftversionuno.CameraView1 has no zero argument constructor
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1597)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1595)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this ?? I am stuck.

Comment: what are you doing. I think before starting the any development you need to learn basic of that langauge. && cut the setupMessageButton() method code and paste in oncreate() method and last remove the other code which you written

Comment: Well I have taken a course on Java, but this is my first time on Android Studio, it is very different. Also, I have been trying many different things to make this work, probably why it looks so messed up. @AmanJham

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.cerezaenterprises.swiftversionuno;


 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;



 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {
 private Button button;
     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraView1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
         });
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
         // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
         int id = item.getItemId();

         //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
         if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
             return true;
         }

         super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

         return true;
       }
 }
```

Comment: It is giving a error (cannot resolve symbol 'button') for                               button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  @Deepak Goyal

Comment: I created it as local variable and it worked thanks!

Comment: After I solved this problem, and click on the camera button, my app crashes and the error on the log cat says my camera view code has no zero argument constructor. Do you think you could help me with that ?